# This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request

Tags: php, html, forms, amazon-web-services, https

```
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.
```

I have configure the website to only accept https on amazon cloudfront.
In a nutshell, you have a php login form, and upon successful login it redirects the user as follow:

```
 if(isset($_POST['login'])){

[...]
        echo "<script>window.open('coursePayment.php?crs_id=$crs_id','_self')</script>";
```

below is the form:

```
 <form style="margin-top:-20px" method='post' action='' class='form-horizontal' role='form'>
       <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeLogin" name="couponCodeLogin">
        <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeLoginAmount" name="couponCodeLoginAmount">
<br><br>
 <div class="group">      
            <input type='text' class='form-control' name='email' required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>

    <div class="group">      
            <input type='password' class='form-control' name='pass' required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Password</label>
    </div>


            <h5 style="color:#FF6400; cursor:context-menu; margin-top:0px" class="displayForgotPassword">Forgot your password? Click here to retrieve it.</h5><br>
            <input type='submit' id='moreInfoButton' name='login' value='Continue' class='btn btn-danger'>                               
          </form>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What the error is trying to tell you is that you cannot use POST. Going to guess that cacheable means GET in this context. You need to go ahead and configure cloud front to allow "upload requests" like POST, PUT, etc. IN this case the request will go to the origin that Cloudfront uses.

Aws docs:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating-console.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html

Look for Allowed HTTP Methods in last link.

Comment: updated answer with links to doc that walk though how you do this in the AWS console

Answer (score 76):

This error happens because CloudFront isn't configured to accept an HTTP request it's being sent (like `POST` or `PATCH`).

To fix it, change your CloudFront distributions settings to accept all HTTP methods.

To do that, click on the `Behaviors` tab of your CloudFront distribution, select the default behavior, click `Edit`, change the `Allowed HTTP Methods` to `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE`, then click `Yes, Edit` in the bottom right to save your changes.

[image: Change Allowed HTTP Methods in a CloudFront distribution]

It may take several minutes for your CloudFront distribution to propagate the changes.

Comment: doesn't work for me. still the distribution supports only cachable requests.

Comment: Thanks @cgenco, It did the work