# Access denied 4030 when trying to create contact information integration with Hubspot

Tags: php, hubspot

I have a contact form which i want to integrate with my Hubspot, but i keep receiving this error message:

```
403 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests. 
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: zzXYHpy8twhlm2q4KvXwkig3hdEa5PobhB2UBh8umgMZK9MLo0J30A==
```

This is the code i am using, my browser is HTTPS and i tried with my local which is HTTP but none of them worked.

```
<?php

        $arr = array(
            'properties' => array(
                array(
                    'property' => 'email',
                    'value' => 'testing@mailinator.com'
                ),
                array(
                    'property' => 'firstname',
                    'value' => 'test'
                ),
                array(
                    'property' => 'lastname',
                    'value' => 'test22'
                ),
                array(
                    'property' => 'phone',
                    'value' => '0123654785'
                )
            )
        );
        $post_json = json_encode($arr);
        $endpoint = 'https://app.hubspot.com/contacts/v1/contacts?hapikey=' . $hapikey;

        $ch = @curl_init();
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_json);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = @curl_exec($ch);
        $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $curl_errors = curl_error($ch);
        @curl_close($ch);
        echo "curl Errors: " . $curl_errors;
        echo "\nStatus code: " . $status_code;
        echo "\nResponse: " . $response;

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253694/this-distribution-is-not-configured-to-allow-the-http-request

Comment: @Ash-b no i saw it before, but did not help me

Comment: `https://app.hubspot.com/ ` try making it `http://` i mean non-secure

Comment: @Ash-b i get this error: 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: Have you added user agent?