# 403 ERROR, This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request

Tags: php, post, amazon-cloudfront, digital-ocean, http-status-code-403

I am new with Digital Ocean.

I am doing make POST in Ubuntu which is DO droplets.

But when I try POST in my php file, I get following error.

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

I already did many googling, but there are many solutions for AWS, but nothing for Digital Ocean.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253694/this-distribution-is-not-configured-to-allow-the-http-request